# Who handles C++ "new" memory allocation failure?

Tags: c++, c, memory-management

In C, people often check null pointers after using malloc. However, in C++, we will use "new". I have done some search and one explanation for the difference between malloc and new is below:
https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/freestore-mgmt#new-malloc-diff

Quote from the link above:

> malloc() reports memory exhaustion by returning 0. new reports allocation and initialization errors by throwing exceptions (bad_alloc).

But how does OS (Linux or windows) react to this bad_alloc exception?

Comment: The OS doesn't react to these things. It is the *cause* of these things. The OS rejects the memory allocation attempt. Look for `VirtualAlloc`, `HeapAlloc`, `mmap` and `sbrk`.

Comment: @ZanLynx: Why are you answering in a _comment_? Use the answer section.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Because there's already a good answer and I just wanted to respond to one part of the question.

Comment: @ZanLynx: Stack Overflow's software supports multiple answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**They don't.** The OS doesn't need to "react" to anything. Your program might want to react to the condition, or it may leave the exception unhandled and terminate. Either way, the memory wasn't allocated and the OS doesn't care any more, if it cared (or even knew about it) in the first place!

Comment: "The OS doesn't care any more" It might not even know anything happened, small allocations rarely even reach the OS levels.

Comment: That is not quite correct. There is OOM killer in Linux, which job is to kill process(es) in case of memory-tight situation.

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux: And it's completely irrelevant.

Comment: @MooingDuck OTOH, a `malloc` implementation that would fail without even trying to ask the OS for more memory would be rather strange.

Comment: @5gon12eder: Strange, but compliant (say, if there is no OS or --- perhaps more realistically outside of embedded dev --- if the implementation has a settable memory limit, which was reached).

Comment: @5gon12eder nothing strange, happens all the time with ulimit, setrlimit, cgroups

Comment: @5gon12eder: I have a couple different allocator classes that do exactly that. Set a memory limit and it throws the bad_alloc exception whenever it would go over the limit. Good for testing too.

Comment: so If the allocation failed with new, and I just start writing using the pointer, then it will over write memory regions starting from 0 (similar to a NULL pointer dereference issue when malloc fails?)?

Comment: @dannycrane: `new`, if it throws, doesn't give you _any_ pointer. It throws. If you used the non-throwing version that returns a NULL pointer then, well, that's a vast oversimplification but, yeah sort of. Just like dereferencing and writing through any other invalid pointer.

Comment: how to find out whether I am using the throwing version or not throwing version?

Comment: @dannycrane: If you don't know, you are using the throwing version.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, I see your point since my question is about linux or windows. But I am actually using a customized OS, could you answer this last question? If you think it is too long, I can open another thread.

Comment: @dannycrane: "I am using a customized OS" Well, since you haven't told me exactly in what way it is "customized" then no, I obviously can't.

Comment: Thank you for the discussion. I have open another thread just for finding out the C++ behavior if memory allocation fails. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29283847/how-to-find-out-the-return-value-if-my-c-new-memory-allocation-failure

Comment: FYI SO is not a forum or discussion board so they are _questions_ not _threads_