# How to find out the return value if my C++ “new” memory allocation failure?

Tags: c++, memory-management, operating-system

In C, people often check null pointers after using malloc. However, in C++, we will use "new". Based on my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29262078/who-handles-c-new-memory-allocation-failure/29262106#29262106), I get to know that new in C++ will give two possible return values on memory allocation failure:

The throwing version: return nothing, program will crash if I try to use (read/write) the variable that is allocated.

The non-throwing version: return NULL pointer.

How can I find out which version my program is using? (Is there any general steps to look for since I would rather not mention the OS I am using to avoid complication)

Comment: It's nothing to do with your OS but a compiler option. In C++11 I believe you can select explicitly. In standard C++, new will throw if it failed, not later on when you try to access the data.

Comment: what does throw mean when I execute my program? new reports allocation and initialization errors by throwing exceptions (bad_alloc). If I do pointer dereference right after "new" which fails, what will happen?

Comment: You can't deference the pointer after new throws, but this causes the current function immediately to exit.

Comment: exit means crash or return -1 or something else?

Comment: Something else, please read some tutorials on exceptions.

Comment: what is that something else? That is the question I am asking in the post....If you can tell me the procedure to find out that, it will be helpful too.

Comment: That's why he said to read tutorials on exceptions. If you knew how exceptions worked, you would know the answer to your question.

Comment: I [already addressed that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29262078/who-handles-c-new-memory-allocation-failure/29262106#comment46729804_29262106), danny.

Answer (score 1):

The standard indicates that an unqualified `new` will be the throwing version, although some (typically embedded) systems offer compiler options to change that default behavior.

If you see `new (std::nothrow) T` then that's the non-throwing version that returns null on failure.

Answer (score 0):

You can find out by looking at the new-expression. A regular new, which throws on failure, looks like

```
new Thing;
```

while a non-throwing new, which returns null on failure, looks like

```
new(std::nothrow) Thing;
```

Answer (score 0):

You know which one you're using because you decided which one to use when you wrote your program.

`new T` will throw on failure; `new (std::nothrow) T` will evaluate to `nullptr` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `new` without specifying a parameter will throw a `std::bad_alloc` exception if it fails.  If your code does not catch this exception, it is likely to terminate to app, or at least kill the calling thread.

Calling `new` with a `std::nothrow` parameter returns `NULL`/`nullptr` if it fails.  If your code does not check for this condition, you are going to encounter a crash when you try to access memory via that pointer.

An app can use `set_new_handler()` to specify a custom handler to detect allocation failures before `new` exits.  Typically this is used to log error messages, or to clear up memory so `new` can retry the allocation.